# Celery Flower with Multiple Workers in Different Docker Containers

Tags: python, celery, fastapi

I've been up and down StackOverflow and Google, but I can't seem to come close to an answer.

**tl;dr** How do I register a dockerized Celery worker in a dockerized Flower dashboard?  How do I point the worker to the Flower dashboard so that the dashboard "knows" about it?

I have 2 FastAPI apps, both deployed with `docker-compose.yml` files. The first app's `compose` file looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/fastapi/Dockerfile
    image: app_web
    # '/start' is the shell script used to run the service
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8010:8000
    env_file:
      - .env/.dev-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:6-alpine

  celery_worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/fastapi/Dockerfile
    image: app_celery_worker
    command: /start-celeryworker
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env/.dev-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis

  flower:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/fastapi/Dockerfile
    image: app_celery_flower
    command: /start-flower
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env/.dev-sample
    ports:
      - 5557:5555
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

So this app is responsible for creating the Celery Flower dashboard.

The second app's `compose` file looks like:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/fastapi/Dockerfile
    image: app_two_web
    # '/start' is the shell script used to run the service
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8011:8000
    env_file:
      - .env/.dev-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:6-alpine

  celery_worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/fastapi/Dockerfile
    image: app_two_celery_worker
    command: /start-celeryworker
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env/.dev-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

I can't get this second app's worker to register in the Celery Flower dashboard running on port 5557. Everything works fine, and I can even launch a second Flower dashboard with the second app if on a different port, but I can't seem to connect the second worker to the first app's Flower dashboard.

This is what `main.py` looks like, for both apps.

```
from project import create_app

app = create_app()
celery = app.celery_app


def celery_worker():
    from watchgod import run_process
    import subprocess

    def run_worker():
        subprocess.call(
            ["celery", "-A", "main.celery", "worker", "-l", "info"]
        )

    run_process("./project", run_worker)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    celery_worker()
```

Thanks for any ideas that I can throw at this.

Answer (score 0):

- First enable event monitoring by putting "-E" in your worker container "command:"
- Second, specify environment variable C_FORCE_ROOT in every worker services in your docker-compose configuration.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The -E sounds on target, but what does C_FORCE_ROOT have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Docker compose and adding the "-E" flag worked perfectly. Note that in my case I defined a network in the Docker compose file which all of the services were joined to. (The same network can be declared in multiple Docker compose files and then it will just  be created once and all services will connect to it from all Docker compose files.)

The problem existed on our AWS ECS cluster as well and the "-E" flag solved it there too.

Flower also has an equivalent [enable_events](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#enable-events) flag.